# Why Bootstrap's select list is not working in google chrome's developer tool mobile view (responsive) option ? Is this BUG or anything else?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, combobox

I am developing an application, in that application i am using select list with Bootstrap's class. My problem is when i test it using chrome's developer tool (f5) and switch it to small devices (for check is this responsive or not) but it does not work as expected! Is this BS bug or chrome's bug?
My code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" name="access" id="access">
     <option value="1" @view>View Only</option>
     <option value="0" @full>Full</option>
   </select>
 </div>
```

Snap Shot:
[Application snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxjAA.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue, but it's Chrome's bug, when I try to select one option from the list, the background becomes black, and my select changes its place, I tested it in Edge and works perfectly, my english is not too good, I hope help you

Comment: Thanks i also faced same problem, may be in real mobile device it will work fine thanks